# One-click sharing with your network

Tags: delicious

I am wondering if it is possible to share a link recorded on Delicious with all the people belonging to your network. I know that you could add the tag `for:auser` for *each* of your friends but I would like to do that by means of a single action.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

Create a network bundle then simply put in your post `for:nameOfTheBundle`